# Why Notification does not show the correct smallIcon?

Tags: android, push-notification

I use below code to display notifications in my Android apps. I can display it but both "*small-Icon*" and "*large-Icon*" are incorrect.They are not even launcher-icon.! I don't know Android where does they get from !!!!
[image: Notification]

- My device is xiaomi-mi5s, is it related to my device? although  other apps like Gmail show correct notifications.
- I tested notifications in API 15,17,26 emulators and everything

  ```
      NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new android.support.v4.app.NotificationCompat.Builder(context, PRIMARY_CHANNEL)
          .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name)
          .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(context.getResources(), R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
          .setContentIntent(getPendingIntent(context))
          .setContentTitle("This is dummy title")
          .setContentText("This is dummy body text")
          .setSound(getDefaultSoundUri())
          .setCategory("My_Category")
          .setDeleteIntent(getOnDismissedPendingIntent(context));

      NotificationManager manager = (NotificationManager) context.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

      if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 26) {
          NotificationChannel chan1 = new NotificationChannel(PRIMARY_CHANNEL,
                  PRIMARY_CHANNEL, NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT);
          chan1.setLightColor(Color.BLUE);
          chan1.setLockscreenVisibility(Notification.VISIBILITY_PRIVATE);
          manager.createNotificationChannel(chan1);
      }

      manager.notify(12121, builder.build());
  ```

Comment: Your `setSmallIcon()` builder is taking a different drawable to your `setLargeIcon()`. Ensure both are the same.

Comment: It does not work.

Comment: Are you sure that you've placed all the versions(mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi, xxhdpi and xxxhdpi)? Also put one copy of icon in general drawable folder.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Large icon and Small icon can be different.

`setSmallIcon()`: sets an icon that should be displayed at status bar when notification was received. If `setLargeIcon()` was not called in the builder, large icon will use small icon drawable. Icon should have size of 24dp.

`setLargeIcon()`: sets an icon that should be displayed at notification in notification list, that can be opened by user by vertical dragging of status bar.

!!! Since API 21, Android requires you to use only single-colour icons with transparency for small icons (e.g. filled contour of Android with only white colour and transparent background).

As a Large icon, you can use icon of any colours, there are no restrictions.

Comment: As I said, I receive correct Notification in emulators.But my own mobile ha problem. Although I could display correct notifications in the past. !

Comment: I has a problem with Xiaomi Redmi Note 2, it was related to alarm manager (device could not wake up after such call, although devices with pure Android could do this). Now I have many problems with notifications and custom intents on Xiaomi devices, maybe this is connected with MIUI on Xiaomi?

Test on other devices. Maybe it might help to know.

Comment: Hey guys, I created some apps at past , and they show notifications correctly in my xiaomi device!! I can't find out why my new app doesn't work! i changed **compileSdkVersion** , **buildToolsVersion** and even Android studio version but it it has not any change yet.